# TinyMCE with multiple models asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I am having a problem with TinyMCE editor in my project!

I have one view that a show more tham one models.

i have this model:

```
public class PaginaPrincipalViews
{
    public List<TNS_Menus> Menus { get; set; }

    public List<ASSOCIADO> Associados { get; set; }
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public List<TNS_Artigos> Artigos { get; set; }
    public List<TNS_Artigos> ArtigosArquivo { get; set; }
    public USUARIO UsarioLogado { get; set; }
   // public TNS_ANUNCIANTES Anunciante { get; set; }

    public PaginaPrincipalViews()
    {
        this.Menus = new List<TNS_Menus>();
        this.Associados = new List<ASSOCIADO>();
        this.Artigos = new List<TNS_Artigos>();
        this.ArtigosArquivo = new List<TNS_Artigos>();
        this.UsarioLogado = new USUARIO();

    }
}
```

another class:

```
   public partial class TNS_Artigos
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string CorpoArtigo { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    public string AliasAutor { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AutorID { get; set; }
    public string UrlImagem { get; set; }
    public bool Publicado { get; set; }
    public bool ExibePaginaInicia { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoriaID { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoCurta { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EncerraEm { get; set; }
}
```

when i call /articles/Create show the editor, but when i call artigles/Edit show me a textbox with HTML code!

Can anyone help-me?

Comment: TinyMce is a textarea replacement. Are you placing a html textarea on your page? TinyMce is very well documented, have looked at their examples?

Comment: The editor works when I use the articles / create because I have only one model on this page, now when I use a class with several models in the same class, it does not work!

Comment: Can you show your view code?